# Can not acces a running instance of embedded Glassfish from browser

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-embedded

I'm trying to use the embedded Glassfish for running some unit tests. I have managed to configure and start the server, but i can't access the management console from my browser. Nor can i access the REST Interface from tha java code. My questions are: Is it possible to access the embedded Glassfish server from the browser or from java code, using REST? If it is, what i am doing wrong?

The code is use is this:

```
    File installDir = new File("e:\\Glassfish3\\glassfish");
    File domainDir = new File(installDir, "domains\\domain1");

    File domainConfig = new File(domainDir, "config");
    File domainXml = new File(domainConfig, "domain.xml");

    Server.Builder builder = new Server.Builder("test");

    EmbeddedFileSystem.Builder efsb = new EmbeddedFileSystem.Builder();
    efsb.installRoot(installDir);
    efsb.instanceRoot(domainDir);
    efsb.configurationFile(domainXml);
    EmbeddedFileSystem efs = efsb.build();
    builder.embeddedFileSystem(efs);

    Server server = builder.build();
    server.createPort(4849);
    server.addContainer(ContainerBuilder.Type.web);

    server.start();
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, i found this [link](http://wikis.sun.com/display/GlassFish/3.2EmbeddedOnePager#3.2EmbeddedOnePager-4.7.Admin%2FConfigImpact%3A) and it seems like the administration console is not available in Glassfish embedded.

The question about the REST interface is still open.